# gifsicle.exe on Windows 7 - Invalid argument error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, animated-gif

I'm trying to build a GIF image from several different GIF images using GIFSICLE.exe utility. Here is the link to the utility that I'm referring here: http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/

I've all the individual GIF frames saved in "Frames-GIFs" folder and the gifsicle.exe is also placed in the same folder. Here is the command line that I'm passing:

```
gifsicle --delay=10 --loop *.gif > test.gif
```

I following error:

```
gifsicle: *.gif: Invalid argument
```

Can someone please guide me to build a proper Command Line for gifsicle and make animated GIF using a series of GIF image files?

---

*P.S.: This is an attempt to make a Screen Recorder in Visual Basic that records screen activity in animated GIF image format. I've completed code that takes screenshots of predefined area at a preset frequency (delay parameter for gifsicle). If you can suggest any better alternative, your suggestions are welcome. :-)

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's a question about how to use an existing program. Try SuperUser.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm not able to build a proper command line parameter. I tried "convert", but it holds my application window until the process is completed. If you can give me an idea to resolve this issue, "convert" from ImageMagick will work for me.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Try www.superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen; I've just posted this question on SuperUser.

Comment: Here it is on Super User: http://superuser.com/q/693593/83235